# Large image causing NullPointerException in emulator

Tags: android

I am having problems with the emulator crashing when drawing a large image. The crash is caused by a NullPointerException when using setBounds on my drawable (so my drawable is null for some reason).

The problem only occurs in the emulator, and not if I load it on to my device (HTC Desire).

My image is a 1080x1658 px jpg. If I specify a much smaller image the problem goes away.

My code looks like this:

```
public class Map {

    private Drawable mapImage;

    public Map(Context context) {
        mapImage = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.north);
    }

    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        mapImage.setBounds(0, 0, 1080, 1658);
        mapImage.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if your application's heap is too big? You can do that with DDMS at eclipse.
An image with that size might be causing big problems.

Furthermore be sure to recycle your old bitmaps to make some space for new ones - they're one of the most problematic things at Android.

You can increase your emulator's heap size in the settings, too - but this doesn't represent the reality as lots of device only have about 32 mb heap.

Comment: Hi, I tried looking at the heap size in the DDMS perspective in eclipse, but since the VM crashes the process is shut down before I can see the heap size (when I open the activity with the large image). I however have another app that shares the code base, but uses a smaller image (900x952), this app does not crash and from what I can tell the heap never goes above 6,070 MB in that app, so I would guess that I am within the default 24 MB of the emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the Max VM Application Heap Size of your emulator to a much higher value, you can go and click Edit and change this value for your AVD. Basically this will increase the amount of memory allocated to each process on your emulator, note that by default, this is set to a higher value on your real device.

[image]

Similar problem: http://androidforums.com/application-development/48495-memory-size-emulator.html

Comment: I guess a bigger heap size will help him with his app but doesn't reflect reality as lots of device out there only have about 32 mb heap size.

Comment: Well pointed out Tim, Mat, you need to make sure you use a smaller image for a smaller device so that it does not exceed the heap size for that device. If you just need to work around the current emulator issue, you can increase the heap size for now.

Comment: Increasing my heap size in the emulator does not seems to "solve" the issue. The VM still crashes.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how much different sizes (and formats) of images take up in memory?